# Javascript to get sharepoint form field value to a variable

Tags: javascript

I want to copy the content of a sharepoint form field to a variable using Javascript.

Eg. I have a field named "Language" in my sharepoint edit form. Now I just want to get the value of that field to a varaible x.

Please help.

BR

Comment: I want to validate that field value to check if there is a blank space. But dont know how to get the field value to a variable. Is there any javascript function to get it? like getElementByID..or something like that?

Comment: Is this SharePoint 2007 or 2010? Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type (e.g. user, lookup, multilookup, text, note, etc.) of field. I am using jQuery in my custom list forms and the name of the field for any given content type will be added to the id of the corresponding html control with the text 'Field' appended to it. However, like any typical asp.net control, the id of the html form control rendered to the client will reflect its control hierarchy so you have to account for that when searching for a field. anyhow, the following works for me if i need to reference fields in my custom forms. ** notice the +Field which implies that the name of the field is concatenated with 'Field'

```
var $titleField = $('input[id*=TitleField]');
var $lookupField = $('select[id*=Name_Of_Field+Field]')
var $multiLookUpCandidate = $('select[id*=Name_Of_Field+Field][id*=SelectCandidate]')
var $multiLookUpResult = $('select[id*=Name_Of_Field+Field][id*=SelectResult]')
var $note = $('textarea[id*=Name_Of_Field+Field]');
```

You can pick up on the trend by viewing source and seaching for your contenttype/sitecolumn field name. You will find it in an html form control id. use that information to learn how to reference other field types.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick help.

@Athens - This answered my questions and now I am able to validate my edit form using javascript.

Comment: No problem! I am doing a lot with jQuery and SharePoint on my current project. I have plenty of useful info to share.

Answer (score 1):

Without posting your code its very difficult to understand what you want to do.... to get a value from a form you can do the following :

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
  <input id="myinput" type="text" value="something" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myinputval = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
```

`myinputval` would be "something" in this example

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Qk6FZ/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I am not sure how to get this id from a sharepoint form.

Comment: Here is my code
<Script type="text/javascript"> 
function PreSaveAction() 
{ 
var filename; 
var fileNameSpecialCharacters = new RegExp('\\s', 'g'); 
try { 
filename = document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_b9448c4d_e46c_4451_ae75_461354197b0f_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField").value; 
}
catch (e) { 
} 
if (fileNameSpecialCharacters.test(filename)) { 
alert("Please remove the special characters from the file attachment name.");
return false; 
} 
else { 
return true; 
} 
} 
</script>

Comment: I dont need the script - i want the HTML has output to the browser

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://depressedpress.com/2012/09/24/obtaining-a-javascript-reference-to-a-sharepoint-field/

Using that function you'd get the reference using something like:

```
var LanguageFld = getFieldRef("Language");
```

Once you have the refernece it's easy to get the value:

```
var CurValue = LanguageFld.value;
```

Hope this helps!